# In Linux is there an API, interface or library to access the electrical power hardware for state, health and historical data?

Tags: api, history, power-management

In Linux, is there an API, interface, or library to access the electrical power hardware (for mains and battery) for state, health and historical data?

Particularly, I'm looking to find out if such subsystems record historical data.

I'm aware that power technology and battery technology could be quite sophisticated - for example, the "intelligent" battery technology that the Apple notebooks are said to have.

But my example is more about general server equipment power and battery supplies and what historical data you can get from them, e.g. how often the mains power cable has been removed and battery taken over, etc.

I need to know this as part of testing such equipment.

Comment: Maybe also a question for serverfault.com ? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think such a thing would be pretty hardware-specific. One general approach is to use SNMP. The manufacturer of the server may have already written various MIBs to allow monitoring of various things and, with some work, one can write their own to take more specialized actions and measurements. If you have newish HP servers, they have a built-in SNMP-like package called iLO, or integrated-lights-out.

Comment: Thanks for the SNMP suggestion. If I have success with that from further research I will feedback here and upvote the post. Obviously I'll continue to look out for other answers for the time being.

Comment: accepted because this is a general approach, though I would expect to use this in combination with something likw 'nut' @Paul Tomblin suggested, perhaps via a generic interface abstraction, also with S.M.A.R.T. and ACPI.

Answer (score 1):

Server equipment doesn't generally have batteries.  UPSes on the other hand do.  I use a program called 'nut' to monitor my UPS, and it uses a bunch of plugins to support multiple different UPS brands.  There is no single API that supports all of them.

Comment: Can I have a url to nut? is it publicly available. No single API for UPSs, fair enough - but there's an opportunity there to standardise.

Comment: URL: http://www.networkupstools.org/ - as for opportunity, are you going to get all the UPS makers to change?  Some of them still use serial ports, some use USB, and some use ethernet for monitoring.

Comment: +1 for URL, thanks @Paul Tomblin And I agree, I wouldn't expect makers to change. If I can make myself aware of the variety of standards I expect to encounter in my work, then it ought to be sufficient to support all of these each in their own specific way. I might also explore any benefit to use or make *software* that helps all of these different systems be viewed in the same standard way.